# Count Up tick volume and down tick volume in a real time bar without security function

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4, pine-script-v5

I want to build a pine script which will count total up ticks volume and total down ticks volume in a real time daily bar. How do I do that? I don't want to use security function because it has limitations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by making use of [varip](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#op_varip) to declare your variables.
Please read through the [documentation on `varip`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Variable_declarations.html#varip) to fully understand how it works.
Then have a look at some open source [example scripts](https://www.tradingview.com/scripts/varip/?script_access=all) to see how it's used.

Example of how it could be implemented:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Intrabar Tick Volume", "ITV", overlay=true)

varip int   tickDirection   = na
varip int   tickCount       = 0
varip float volumeUp        = 0
varip float volumeDown      = 0
varip float prevTickVolume  = 0
varip float prevTickClose   = 0

if barstate.isnew
    tickCount       := 0
    volumeUp        := 0
    volumeDown      := 0
    prevTickVolume  := 0
    prevTickClose   := close[1]
else
    tickCount       += 1
    tickDirection   := close > prevTickClose ? 1 : close < prevTickClose ? -1 : 0

    if tickDirection == 1 //uptick
        volumeUp += volume - prevTickVolume
    else if tickDirection == -1 //downtick
        volumeDown += volume - prevTickVolume

    // Save data of current tick to use as previous tick values on next tick.
    prevTickClose   := close
    prevTickVolume  := volume

plotchar(tickCount, 'tickCount', '')
plotchar(close, 'close', '')
plotchar(tickDirection, 'tickDirection', '')
plotchar(volume, 'volume', '')
plotchar(volumeUp, 'volumeUp', '')
plotchar(volumeDown, 'volumeDown', '')
```

Comment: I have already tried it. But how do I get the price of the last tick. Not the current tick.

Comment: I have tried it in different way. Using varip I get the total tick. Can't differentiate between up and down tick. how do i do it? Pls help. I am new to the pinescript.

Comment: I've added a code example of how it could be implemented.